# AJAX action through direct link

Tags: ajax

I have an existing AJAX action that's already defined by the theme I'm using. The action deletes a search item request, and I'd like to use it as a direct link - like an Unsubscribe link - emailed to the user along with the search results...

Something like the following URL: `https://domain.tld/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=delete_saved_search_item=&search_item_id=17` but I get a 0 on the screen and a 400 Bad Request in the Headers.

Basically in the JS it's defined like this:

```
            $.post(ajaxurl,
                {
                    action: 'delete_saved_search_item',
                    search_item_id: search_item_id,
                },
                function (response) {
                    response = JSON.parse(response);
                    if (response.success) {
                        search_item.remove();
                    }
                }
            );
```

so I suppose it expects a POST request, not a GET one... Is there any workaround to make this work? Like creating a page with a custom cURL that would imitate the POST form submission? Anyone done something like this? The good thing is I didn't notice any use of nonce, so I suppose this alone makes it easier to handle, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WordPress' [generic POST/GET handler `wp-admin/admin-post.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-admin/admin-post.php/)

Don't let the name confuse you - it accepts both GET/POST, and just like `admin-ajax.php` it accepts both authorised (admin) and non-authorised (public) requests.

```
function wpse_406199_custom_action() {
    // Do something!

    // Maybe redirect back to where they came from?
    wp_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
    exit;
}

// Non-logged-in requests
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_wpse_406199_custom_action', 'wpse_406199_custom_action' );

// Logged-in requests
add_action( 'admin_post_wpse_406199_custom_action', 'wpse_406199_custom_action' );
```

And to get the URL:

```
$action_url = admin_url( 'admin-post.php?action=wpse_406199_custom_action' );
```

Comment: I will try it and report back (though it already looks like it'll do the job for my case). Thank you so much! :D

Comment: I asked this question for one project, and I'll end up using it for another one that fits... I have one question though: The case I'll be using it takes place in the public side of website, but the user has to be logged in, in order to perform the action... So which of the two should I use? The nopriv or the other one?

Comment: @FayeD. If you just want to handle logged-in users, then "the other one" (_not_ nopriv)

Comment: Thank you very much! :D

Comment: For some reason `admin_post_<my_action>` didn't work. The action never fired to process the call, and so the AJAX request kept returning a 400 Bad Request. It worked only after I googled the error and changed `admin_post_<my_action>` to `wp_ajax_<my_action>`... I have no clue why it didn't work! Do you?

Comment: @FayeD. Because you're probably still using  the JS var `ajaxurl` that points to `admin-ajax.php` and not `admin-post.php`?

Comment: Ah, you are absolutely right! In fact I named the JS var `ajax_url`, but indeed I used the PHP code `'ajax_url'  => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=mark_quiz&status=ran_out_of_time&quiz_id=' . $ticket->ID ), 'mark_quiz' ),` to produce it! Is there any difference between the two methods? I only need to set a postmeta `completed` for that post...